# Excel dates data cannot calculate difference between two dates?

Tags: excel

The worksheet is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/kapavvj6yc0nhdr/recruitment%20%282%29.xls

I have data that were collected from our IT department, and it shows dates which I am trying to analyze.

When I calculate the difference between two dates with a simple subtraction function =(A1-A2), I get either #VALUE or a wrong result in numbers. I have tried to google it, I've tried to use different functions to no avail.

What I have found in the worksheet is that some dates are displayed as dates when I view with (CTRL+`) and some are shown as serial numbers. So this might be the issue I guess.

I need to calculate the differences between two dates in this worksheet correctly with no errors. Any input is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Two things:**

First, your dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format, as evidenced by the date in `D2`, which is `22/11/2012/`. Taking this into consideration, the proper formula in `J2` should be `=F2-$D2`, dragged to the right. The original formula is subtracting the wrong way, which would have resulted in negative time, hence an error.

Second, if your regional settings prevent you from reading this as the default, modify the dates to the proper format. Some of them are considered strings and some are valid dates. This is a common problem with dates. On my end, the following UDF works nicely enough.

```
Function ModifyDate(sDate As String) As Date
    Dim sDay As String, sMonth As String, sYear As String
    Dim divOne As Long, divTwo As Long
    divOne = InStr(sDate, "/")
    divTwo = InStrRev(sDate, "/")
    sDay = Left(sDate, divOne - 1)
    sMonth = Mid(sDate, divOne + 1, divTwo - divOne - 1)
    sYear = Right(sDate, 4)
    ModifyDate = DateValue(sMonth & "/" & sDay & "/" & sYear)
End Function
```

Highlighting the dates and calling the function like so results into all of them being converted to `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

```
Sub ModifyRangeDates()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Selection
        Cell.Value = ModifyDate(CStr(Cell.Value))
    Next
End Sub
```

We then apply the formula I gave in the first paragraph, drag down and right. Finally, modified file is [here](http://www.wikiupload.com/U3YX3CEHJ59WNAM).

Enjoy.

Comment: That's just impressive. I am eternally thankful, but one more thing, it seems that the functions =E2-$D$2 is repeating for each cell with the correct E# cell but with the same D2 cell, which is not what I wanted and couldn't apply automatically by double clicking the first "days taken to approve".

Comment: Thank you. If this worked for you, kindly accept the answer. This is how we say thanks in SO. :)

Comment: I already put you as best answer, thanks again. But could you read my above comment, I am still struggling with the function.

Comment: Gaffe on my part: change `J2`'s formula to `=E2-$D2` and drag down and right. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the regional settings.  The spreadsheet was created with MM/DD/YYYY settings.  When the dates were entered in "DD/MM/YYYY" format, those that had a date of 12 or less was interpreted as a MM/DD/YYYY date.  Otherwise it was taken as text.

Rather than write a UDF, I put a formula into an adjacent column to compute the "proper" date for each entry.  For example I would insert a column called "Assessed (calc)" and use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(H2),DATE(YEAR(H2),DAY(H2),MONTH(H2)),DATE(RIGHT(H2,4),MID(H2,FIND("/",H2)+1,FIND("/",H2,1+FIND("/",H2))-FIND("/",H2)-1),LEFT(H2,FIND("/",H2)-1)))
```

The formula checks if the "Date" is a number, in which case it reverses the month and date and generates the date value.  If it is a text, it parses the text to extract the correct values.  (Made more complicated because some of the dates have only one digit for the month)

I would repeat this for each column of dates, and then do your calculations on the the results.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you format your resulting column as a NUMBER and the other columns as DATES.

Try using the DATEDIF function:

To get the difference in days from today's date and the date value in B2 column:

```
=DATEDIF(B2, TODAY(), "d")
```